# How to write a type that uses either of two interfaces?

Tags: typescript

Function `foo` must accept either an object with a signature of
`parentId: string; id: string; text: string;`
or
`parentId: string; id: string; type: "separator";`

```
interface IMenuItemGeneric {
  parentId: string;
  id: string;
}
interface ITextItem extends IMenuItemGeneric {
  text: string;
}
interface ISeparatorItem extends IMenuItemGeneric {
  type: "separator";
}
export type IMenuItem = ITextItem | ISeparatorItem;

function foo({
  parentId,
  id,
  text,
  type,
  contexts,
}: IMenuItem): void {
 // some code 
}
```

TS says `property 'text' doesn't exist on type IMenuItem`.
So how can this typing be achieved without code duplication?

Comment: `function foo(item: IMenuItem)`?

Comment: nope. still gives the same error. it additionally says `property 'text' doesn't exist on type ISeparatorItem`

Comment: No it doesn't. What generates this error is the code that you didn't post

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the union type really means it's one or the other. Therefore TypeScript won't let you access the `text` property because it doesn't exist on both interfaces.

#### Casting

Without changing anything about the types, you'll have to resort to casting to make it compile:

```js
function foo(item: IMenuItem): void {
  console.log((item as ITextItem).text);
}
```

#### Discriminated Union

Alternatively you could make use of [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). For this you would add a `type: "text"` property to the `ITextItem` interface.

```js
interface ITextItem extends IMenuItemGeneric {
  type: "text";
  text: string;
}
```

Because now both interfaces have a `type` property, you can access it without casting. Even more importantly the compiler will use it to narrow down the actual type of the passed item:

```js
function foo(item: IMenuItem): void {
  if (item.type === 'text') {
    // type inside here is ITextItem
    console.log(item.text);
  } else {
    // type inside here is ISeparatorItem
  }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkIgK6sgWwHEtpgFkBvAKGWQAc4osxUATALmQGcwpQBzANw1kwDt14DhAXyqhIsRClQAVCAA8WBZBsghWXNJhx4IREn3LVaYAJ50InAESRNT4Td2cefEEKqy8tDwSGgAyhAMUHBgAPZQpvg6mlgGRli4BMQgpFYidg7OXJGMMfHuAVQadPFgyAXKxplmyAC8yAAKjGDAcAA2ADyquokAfMgAZJ3dvYOoEVFlCQTjUxgZidm5wlQw2CAIPbEgyDCxsQAUwASc6yYEAJScAG6xYpQiwDDIVwQAdA02q12gByVxgEEPD60WgAelh9XsKFAXDEKAAFtBkYZhppEiJaAhjlxYn0IH8+rF+L8zADdA8PMhpDo+sVoTD4YiHKIQKjWBisaIcQtSnFlmYRLJpEA)

#### Merged Type

Lastly if you'd rather have `item` be of a type where all non-common properties are possibly undefined like this:

```js
{
    parentId: string;
    id: string;
    type?: "separator";
    text?: string;
}
```

You can do this instead:

```js
export type IMenuItem = Partial<ITextItem> & Partial<ISeparatorItem> & IMenuItemGeneric;
```

In this case it would even be possible to use the destructuring argument:

```js
function foo({
  parentId,
  id,
  text,
  type
}: IMenuItem): void {
  console.log(text); // text has type: string | undefined
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkIgK6sgWwHEtpgFkBvAKGWQAc4osxUATALmQGcwpQBzANw1kwDt14DhAXyqhIsRClQAVCAA8WBZBsghWXNJhx4IREn3LVakTZx58QQqrPnR4SNAGUIDKHDAAeyhTfB1NLAMjLFwCYhBSKxEwAE86CE4AIi5fRgDgzJkqDTpgsGRU9OiTbQBeZAAFRjBgOAAbAB5VXVCAPmQAMkbm1s7UHz98kIJ+oYwY0PjE4SoYbBAEFsCQZBhAwIAKa3pGZjYAGhExS5tdG4q0iBdOeZqzAEpOADdAsUoRBDbLiBNoQAB0bUC-AOtjA7xkQA)

---

Which approach the best is for you is hard to say. It depends a lot on what you are doing inside of `foo`.